# move activity to another activity using Finger

Tags: android, gesture

In my app, I want that using finger movement from left-to-right in Activity A should call Activity B. Similarly, if i move it right-to-left, it should go back to the previous Activity, i.e, Activity A.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are several ways to achieve what you're talking about.

You could use the gesture builder to listen for a swipe and then fire your intents to start the activity.

Without knowing more, you may also want to look at page viewer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define your gestures with the android gesture tool then you have to implement a gesture listener to listen for gesture events

[Basic Gesture Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection) - stackoverflow

[Introduction to Gestures](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/) - mobile tuts

---

Source: [Android: Slide gesture and animation for switching between tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797734/android-slide-gesture-and-animation-for-switching-between-tabs)